# axis2 1.5.4 java enum support

Tags: apache-axis

I have an embedded axis2 service in my web application. When I try to create a wsdl it creates soemthing like

```
<xs:complexType name="AdminState">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:Enum">
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
```

But using this I am unable to create the client code. Eclipse complains about the following error

```
src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:Enum'. It was detected that 'xs:Enum' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///...xyz.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:Enum' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///..xyz.wsdl'.
```

Does Axis2 support enums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it does

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3967

I've been waiting on a fix as well

---

EDIT (07/18/2012): Seems like Axis2 1.7.0 now has support for enums. Time to test this out

Comment: i was wondering if you have tested it out yet?? i cant for the life of me build axis2 with enum support. I have tried applying the patches, i am not sure if i am correct, but i have tried applying it, but dry runs always gives me a bunch of failures

Comment: unfortunately no. haven't had a chance to test this out yet. I might wait for the official release (which for some reason still hasn't happened yet)

Answer (score 2):

Axis2 existing released versions does not support Enum parameters, java level or wsdl level.

But I would like to say that **present trunk (1.7.0) of Axis2 supports JDK5 Enum** in java level as well as wsdl level.

You can find my blog post [Introducing Enum support with Apache Axis2](http://shameerarathnayaka.blogspot.com/2011/09/introducing-enum-support-with-apache.html) that explains how to use Enum support with Axis2 and how we can write a wsdl file which support Enum.